# Como extrair a chave pública de um certificado .pem para utilizar com openssh

Tags: amazon-aws, ssh, openssl

Tenho uma chave privada `rsa` formatado como `PEM` emitido pelo serviço de geração de chaves da Amazon (AWS). Preciso extrair a chave pública, a partir da chave privada para utilizar no arquivo `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` em outras instâncias.

Como faço para extrair a chave pública tendo a chave privada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para extrair a chave pública, utilize o comando `ssh-keygen` como abaixo:

```
ssh-keygen -f chave_privada.pem -y > chave_publica.pub
```